# Is there a C/C++ API for mapserver/mapscript?

Tags: c++, mapserver

I know there is APIs for mapserver through mapscript in php & python.
but i want using mapserver in a existing C/C++ program.
how can i use mapserver in my codes?

Comment: This: https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/tree/master ? This *is* C, so yes, you can connect it with your own C code.

Comment: thanks @deviantfan. I know mapaserver is C but the code is so complicated. I need a documented, simple api/interface to work, not a lot of low-level c code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access MapServer through the [MapScript](https://mapserver.org/mapscript/mapscript.html) [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) API.  Which supports C/C++ inter al.